# What does it mean if the Thevenin voltage is 0?

Tags: thevenin

Does it mean that we can't make an equivalent circuit using the Thevenin Theorem? My question specifically is when using theoretical circumstances on this image. Theoretically speaking the Vth = Vab = 0. What happens then? [image]

Comment: this is actually a very important example : a lot of measurement techniques involve this condition, called a "bridge" or "Wheatstone bridge" which is currently "balanced" - for example, measuring the resistances in a strain gauge. What you found is an important characteristic : the measurement is independent of the voltage source V3 (so battery state doesn't introduce measurement errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Does it mean that we can't make an equivalent circuit using the
> Thevenin Theorem?*

No, you **can** make an equivalent circuit but, the voltage source will be 0 volts. The equivalent circuit will be just a resistor (450 Ω by my calculation) connected to 0 volts.